# Given the following code, how many complex objects are created in memory?

Tags: javascript

Given the following code, how many complex objects are created in memory?

```
function Foo() {
  this.one = function() {
    return "one";
  }
}

var f = new Foo();    

Foo.two = function() {
  return "two";
};
```

My guess:

1. `Foo` constructor function object
2. `f.__proto__` instance of `Foo` constructor function object
3. `f`
4. `one` function object
5. `two` function object

Comment: Note that [`f.__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is non–standard. A compliant reference is `Foo.prototype`.

Comment: This is completely implementation dependent.

Comment: `f.one` and `Foo.two` will also have their own prototypes, even though you're not using them as constructors.

Comment: @RobG [`f.__proto__` is standard](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__), [just a newer standard](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html). (Yes, I know that's a draft but if you read every email in esdiscuss it has been discussed over and over and it's here to say - fwiw I hate it).

Comment: @Benjamin please can you supply a link to esdiscuss?

Comment: @Ben in general http://esdiscuss.org/ , but if you'd like to participate https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/es-discuss and about `__proto__` specifically, most recently http://esdiscuss.org/topic/readdition-of-proto

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum—seems to me that a **draft specification** is not a standard. `__proto__` has a chequered past, I would not be confident that it will be in the final verison of ECMAScript Ed 6 that might become the next standard (note the fate of ed 4) some time in the future.

Comment: It has been standardized. That part is done. The specification as a whole is still not released but the bits about `__proto__` are done. Funny enough - the main (and annoying) reason is Zepto.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It isn't standardized. What makes you think it's immune from the possibility of removal?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum—I live in hope. ;-). I can't understand the Zepto rationale (I visited your link), does a single (not well written IMHO) library cause changes to a standard? It's a bit like qSA returning static collections because that's how JS libraries implemented them. The libraries also return Arrays, but qSA returns a collection. I'm at a loss. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is tricky since the specification does not say anything about objects created in memory.

**JavaScript has a lot of different implementations** like v8 in Chrome, JSC in Safari, SpiderMonkey in Firefox, JScript and Chakra in IE, Rhino as a scripting engine in Java and so on. Not to mention other more esoteric implementations.

Even worse, the implementation *does* specify things like a `VariableEnvironment` of the function and mentions that it's not implementation detail but just a deductive tool to make the specification easier to read.

Given the code above - **a "clever" engine can allocate exactly zero objects here.**

Why? The code above has no side effects at all. You're not calling `Foo` or using `f` anywhere and it's 'dead code' in the sense it's not really used.

---

That said, ignoring that "tiny" issue - there are a few things depending on how the code is used: For one - the strings `"foo"` and `"one"` might be allocated (they're primitive, but might need boxing depending on use).

Alternatively the engine can [inline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) these functions altogether. If it does, `one` and `two` don't get allocated but rather inlined directly.

So - this question is really impossible to answer accurately :)

Comment: One caveat is that if the code is global, then all objects would need to be created. The compiler can't tell what code may be loaded in the future that will rely on these objects.

Comment: Ok thanks. On Chrome I was interested to observe that the __proto__ appeared to point to a unique instance of Foo, onto which properties could be added that are not visible in the prototype chain. Can you confirm this observation?

Comment: Whose `__proto__` are you referring to?

Comment: f.          Comments must be 15 chars.

Comment: @Ben `f.__proto__ === Foo.prototype; // true`

Comment: `f`'s `__proto__` points to an instance of an object created when `Foo` was created - it's `.prototype` property. Here's the actual code:  [`Handle<JSObject> prototype = NewJSObjectFromMap(new_map);`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/factory.cc#L611) and here's the specification: http://es5.github.io/#x13.2 . It doesn't get created every time you create an instance created with  `Foo` as a constructor, it's shared across all instances created with `Foo`.

Comment: its :( I hate not being able to edit silly grammar mistakes. Also forgot to ping @Ben so there we go.